# When does Ansible AWX install postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, ansible-awx

I tried installing Ansible AWX. However, AWX also installs PostgreSQL on the system (I am using kubernetes for AWX btw). I understand that PostgreSQL is one of the requirements for AWX.

Now, for another project, I have to install PostgreSQL (on Kubernetes itself). I looked up a method online and it is working. However, is there some way I can do it automatically, just like the installation of AWX?

Thanks,
Suhas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

This can be achieved by using the `awx-operator`. Below is a Demo installation of `Helm`. By default `awx` and `PG` db are located on the same worker node, but this requires a default `SC`

---

#### Helm Deployment

Configuring Helm sources for awx-operator

```bash
┌──[root@vms81.liruilongs.github.io]-[~/AWK]
└─$helm repo add awx-operator https://ansible.github.io/awx-operator/
"awx-operator" has been added to your repository.
┌──[root@vms81.liruilongs.github.io]──[~/AWK]
└─$helm repo update
Grab the latest from your diagram repository as we grab it...
... Successfully get updates from the "liruilong_repo" chart repository
... Successfully get updates from the "elastic" chart library
... Successfully obtained updates from the "prometheus-community" chart repository
... Successfully obtained updates from the "azure" chart repository
... Unable to get updates from "ali" chart repository (https://apphub.aliyuncs.com).
        Failed to fetch https://apphub.aliyuncs.com/index.yaml: 504 gateway timeout
... Successfully getting updates from the "awx-operator" chart library
... Successfully fetching updates from the "stable" chart library
Update completed. ⎈ Have fun! ⎈
```

Search awx-operator for Chart

```bash
┌──[root@vms81.liruilongs.github.io]-[~/AWK]
└─$helm search repo awx-operator
NAME                            CHART VERSION   APP VERSION     DESCRIPTION
awx-operator/awx-operator       0.30.0          0.30.0          A Helm chart for the AWX Operator
```

Custom parameter installation `helm install my-awx-operator awx-operator/awx-operator -n awx --create-namespace -f myvalues.yaml`.

If you use a custom installation, you need to enable the corresponding switches in `myvalues.yaml`, you can configure HTTPS, standalone PG database, LB, LDAP authentication, etc. The file template can be found in the chart package under pull, and use the value.yaml inside for the template.

We use the default configuration here to install, no need to specify a configuration file.

```bash
┌──[root@vms81.liruilongs.github.io]-[~/AWK]
└─$helm install -n awx --create-namespace my-awx-operator awx-operator/awx-operator
Name: my-awx-operator
Last deployed. mon oct 10 16:29:24 2022
namespace: awx
Status: Deployed
Revision: 1
Test suite: none
Notes.
AWX operator is installed in Helm Chart version 0.30.0.
┌──[root@vms81.liruilongs.github.io]──[~/AWK]
└─$
```

After looking at the POD status

```bash
┌──[root@vms81.liruilongs.github.io]-[~/awx/awx-operator]
└─$kubectl  get pods
NAME                                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
awx-demo-postgres-13-0                             0/1     Pending   0          105s
awx-operator-controller-manager-79ff9599d8-2v5fn   2/2     Running   0          128m
┌──[root@vms81.liruilongs.github.io]-[~/awx/awx-operator]
└─$kubectl  get svc
NAME                                              TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
awx-demo-postgres-13                              ClusterIP   None            <none>        5432/TCP   5m48s
awx-operator-controller-manager-metrics-service   ClusterIP   10.107.17.167   <none>        8443/TCP   132m
```

pg corresponding pod: awx-demo-postgres-13-0 `pending` now, look at the events

```bash
┌──[root@vms81.liruilongs.github.io]-[~/awx/awx-operator]
└─$kubectl describe pods awx-demo-postgres-13-0 | grep -i -A 10 event
Event.
  Type Reason Age From Message
  ---- ------ ---- ---- -------
  Warning FailedScheduling 23s (x8 over 7m31s) default-scheduler 0/3 nodes are available: 3 pods have unbound direct PersistentVolumeClaims.
┌──[root@vms81.liruilongs.github.io]-[~/awx/awx-operator]
└─$kubectl get pvc
name status volume capacity access mode storage class age
postgres-13-awx-demo-postgres-13-0 Pending 10m
┌──[root@vms81.liruilongs.github.io]-[~/awx/awx-operator]
└─$kubectl describe pvc postgres-13-awx-demo-postgres-13-0 | grep -i -A 10 event
Event.
  Type Reason Age From Message
  ---- ------ ---- ---- -------
  Normal FailedBinding 82s (x42 over 11m) persistentvolume-controller no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set.
┌──[root@vms81.liruilongs.github.io]-[~/awx/awx-operator]
└─$kubectl get sc
No resources found
```

OK ,the reason for Pending is that there is no default SC

For stateful applications, we need to create a default SC (dynamic volume provisioning) before generating a `statefulset`, which will dynamically handle the creation of PVs and PVCs and generate data storage for PGs, so we need to create a SC here.

Here, for convenience, we use `local storage` as the back-end storage. In general, PV can only be network storage and does not belong to any Node, so it is a bit more by way of NFS, and the SC will specify the allocator through the provisioner field. After the storageClass is created, the user uses the default SC's allocation storage when defining the pvc.

To confirm successful creation

```bash
┌──[root@vms81.liruilongs.github.io]-[~/awx/awx-operator]
└─$kubectl get sc
name provisioner reclaimpolicy volumebindingmode allowvolumeexpansion age
local-path rancher.io/local-path delete WaitForFirstConsumer false 2m6s
```

Set to default SC:

https://kubernetes.io/zh-cn/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/change-default-storage-class/

```bash
┌──[root@vms81.liruilongs.github.io]-[~/awx/awx-operator]
└─$kubectl patch storageclass local-path -p '{"metadata": {"comments":{"storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class": "true"}}'
storageclass.storage.k8s.io/local-path patched
┌──[root@vms81.liruilongs.github.io]-[~/awx/awx-operator]
└─$kubectl get pods
NAME                                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
awx-demo-postgres-13-0                             0/1     Pending   0          46m
awx-operator-controller-manager-79ff9599d8-2v5fn   2/2     Running   0          173m
```

Export yaml file, delete and recreate

```bash
┌──[root@vms81.liruilongs.github.io]-[~/awx/awx-operator]
└─$kubectl get pvc postgres-13-awx-demo-postgres-13-0  -o yaml > postgres-13-awx-demo-postgres-13-0.yaml
┌──[root@vms81.liruilongs.github.io]-[~/awx/awx-operator]
└─$kubectl delete -f postgres-13-awx-demo-postgres-13-0.yaml
persistentvolumeclaim "postgres-13-awx-demo-postgres-13-0" deleted
┌──[root@vms81.liruilongs.github.io]-[~/awx/awx-operator]
└─$kubectl apply -f postgres-13-awx-demo-postgres-13-0.yaml
persistentvolumeclaim/postgres-13-awx-demo-postgres-13-0 created
```

Check the status of the pvc, here you need to wait a while, Bound means it has been bound.

```bash
┌──[root@vms81.liruilongs.github.io]-[~/awx/awx-operator]
└─$kubectl get pvc
NAME                                 STATUS    VOLUME   CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
postgres-13-awx-demo-postgres-13-0   Pending                                      local-path     3s
┌──[root@vms81.liruilongs.github.io]-[~/awx/awx-operator]
└─$kubectl describe pvc postgres-13-awx-demo-postgres-13-0 | grep -i -A 10 event
Events:
  Type    Reason                 Age   From                                                                                                Message
  ----    ------                 ----  ----                                                                                                -------
  Normal  WaitForPodScheduled    42s   persistentvolume-controller                                                                         waiting for pod awx-demo-postgres-13-0 to be scheduled
  Normal  ExternalProvisioning   41s   persistentvolume-controller                                                                         waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "rancher.io/local-path" or manually created by system administrator
  Normal  Provisioning           41s   rancher.io/local-path_local-path-provisioner-7c795b5576-gmrx4_d69ca393-bcbe-4abb-8b22-cd8db3b26bf8  External provisioner is provisioning volume for claim "awx/postgres-13-awx-demo-postgres-13-0"
  Normal  ProvisioningSucceeded  39s   rancher.io/local-path_local-path-provisioner-7c795b5576-gmrx4_d69ca393-bcbe-4abb-8b22-cd8db3b26bf8  Successfully provisioned volume pvc-44b7687c-de18-45d2-bef6-8fb2d1c415d3
┌──[root@vms81.liruilongs.github.io]-[~/awx/awx-operator]
└─$kubectl get pvc
NAME                                 STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
postgres-13-awx-demo-postgres-13-0   Bound    pvc-44b7687c-de18-45d2-bef6-8fb2d1c415d3   8Gi        RWO            local-path     53s
┌──[root@vms81.liruilongs.github.io]-[~/awx/awx-operator]
└─$
┌──[root@vms81.liruilongs.github.io]-[~/awx-operator/crds]
└─$kubectl get pv
NAME                                       CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                                    STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
pvc-44b7687c-de18-45d2-bef6-8fb2d1c415d3   8Gi        RWO            Delete           Bound    awx/postgres-13-awx-demo-postgres-13-0   local-path              54s
```

Look at the status of the POD, here the PG-DB related POD is created successfully

Here you need to wait a while, you will see the Pods are normal

```bash
┌──[root@vms81.liruilongs.github.io]-[~/ansible]
└─$kubectl get pods
NAME                                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
awx-demo-65d9bf775b-hc58x                          4/4     Running   0          79m
awx-demo-postgres-13-0                             1/1     Running   0          143m
awx-operator-controller-manager-79ff9599d8-m7t8k   2/2     Running   0          81m
```

View SVC Access Test

```bash
┌──[root@vms81.liruilongs.github.io]-[~/ansible]
└─$kubectl get svc
NAME                                              TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
awx-demo-postgres-13                              ClusterIP   None             <none>        5432/TCP       143m
awx-demo-service                                  NodePort    10.104.176.210   <none>        80:30066/TCP   79m
awx-operator-controller-manager-metrics-service   ClusterIP   10.108.71.67     <none>        8443/TCP       82m
┌──[root@vms81.liruilongs.github.io]-[~/ansible]
└─$curl 192.168.26.82:30066
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><script nonce="cw6jhvbF7S5bfKJPsimyabathhaX35F5hIyR7emZNT0=" type="text/javascript">window.....
┌──[root@vms81.liruilongs.github.io]-[~/ansible]
└─$
```

Get Password

```bash
┌──[root@vms81.liruilongs.github.io]-[~/ansible]
└─$kubectl get secrets
NAME                                          TYPE                                  DATA   AGE
awx-demo-admin-password                       Opaque                                1      146m
awx-demo-app-credentials                      Opaque                                3      82m
awx-demo-broadcast-websocket                  Opaque                                1      146m
awx-demo-postgres-configuration               Opaque                                6      146m
awx-demo-receptor-ca                          kubernetes.io/tls                     2      82m
awx-demo-receptor-work-signing                Opaque                                2      82m
awx-demo-secret-key                           Opaque                                1      146m
awx-demo-token-sc92t                          kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      82m
awx-operator-controller-manager-token-tpv2m   kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      84m
default-token-864fk                           kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      4h32m
redhat-operators-pull-secret                  Opaque                                1      146m
sh.helm.release.v1.my-awx-operator.v1         helm.sh/release.v1                    1      84m
┌──[root@vms81.liruilongs.github.io]-[~/awx-operator/crds]
└─$echo $(kubectl get secret awx-demo-admin-password -o jsonpath="{.data.password}" | base64 --decode)
tP59YoIWSS6NgCUJYQUG4cXXJIaIc7ci
┌──[root@vms81.liruilongs.github.io]-[~/awx-operator/crds]
└─$
```

#### Access test

The default service is published as NodePort, so we can access it from any subnet IP via node plus port:http://192.168.26.82:30066/#/login